# Scala build an arraybuffer of the same length with integers

Tags: scala, copy, arraybuffer

I have an `ArrayBuffer` from which I want to convert all objects to their respective size to an existing buffer:

```
trait Obj {
  def size: Int
}

def copySizes(input: ArrayBuffer[Obj], output: ArrayBuffer[Int]): Unit = {
  output.clear()
  input foreach { obj =>
    output += obj.size
  }
}
```

Is there a better idiomatic way to describe copySizes in scala ?
I was thinking about a syntax like:

```
input.mapTo(_.size, output)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

```
output ++= input.view.map(_.size)
```

which has a non-negligible additional overhead (~2x runtime) but is more compact.  You can write your version more compactly, though:

```
input.foreach{ output += _.size }
```

so I don't see much reason not to use it.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer - Of course.  You wanted it in an existing buffer!  Otherwise you just `input.map(_.size)`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying to foldLeft on the input buffer using the output buffer as the accumulator and doing the append in the function body?

```
val output = input.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer[Int]())(_ += _.size)
```

As @Rex Kerr mentioned, there might be a performance hit here vs the `foreach` that you were doing, but I wasn't sure that this was a high performance need piece of code.  I guess it depends on how many items are in the buffer and how often this code is hit.  If it's a low number of items or this is not a piece of code that is consistently hit, then you might be better with something that is more functional (the fold) vs something that is more side effect based (the foreach).

There generally comes a time when writing Scala code where you have to make that decision; do I care about functional purity/pretty scala code or is this something that needs to be optimized.  I try to stay on the purely functional side when possible and then performance test my system and find hotspots and optimize when needed.  Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or something like that) =)

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: @MikaëlMayer - `(output /: input){ _ += _.size }`, but it's ~4x slower.

Comment: @Rex Kerr is this ~4x dip a given for folding or did you actually run a set of samples to gauge the performance impact of folding?  If you sampled, how many samples and how many items in the input buffer?

Comment: @cmbaxter - It's not a given, but it's fairly typical.  I benchmarked with an array of 1024 strings in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was just curious if the overhead was due to the additional function call per iteration in the fold and it so if JIT might be able to optimize/inline if warmed up enough.

Comment: @cmbaxter - Everything was fully warmed up.  I use a benchmarking framework similar in spirit to Google Caliper.  The function call is probably part of it, but I haven't dissected the code to that level of detail.